# Why does ˜/ not work on my Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, bash, terminal

If I try to `cd ˜/` it responds:

```
-bash: "cd: ˜/: No such file or directory"
```

I also don't seem to have a `.bash_profile` or `.profile`.

Comment: Your PATH is broken, which makes sense if you have no .bash_profile or .profile. Check the answer at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7076/multiple-bash-command-not-found-messages-in-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-unix

Comment: I sort of thought so, but all the commands work... just not ˜/ (that i've found) FYI when i type set my path looks like > PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's the wrong tilde character. You typed a "small tilde" ([unicode U+02DC](http://codepoints.net/U+02DC)), when you want a plain ASCII tilde character ([unicode U+007E](http://codepoints.net/U+007E)).  Compare the following commands:

```
cd ~    # plain tilde: this works
cd ˜    # small tilde: doesn't work, because there's no file named "˜"
```

Comment: Soooo then where on my keyboard do i find the "Big" tilde, I mean the tilde character next the 1 key has worked for me in the past.  This just seems to be a recent event.  I guess it's possible that the key got re-mapped somehow???

Comment: Not doubting you answer (as i copied your cd command to my terninal and viola)... but I guess the real question is how do i fix it

Comment: @Bert Smith: Sounds like the correct key on the keyboard. Check your language and regional settings control panel (I'm not sure about the correct terminology for OS X).

Comment: Does that key type the standard tilde or small tilde in other apps (e.g. if you type a tilde in TextEdit, then copy & paste it into Terminal, which one do you get)? If it's typing the small tilde everywhere, look in System Preferences -> Language & Text pane -> Text and Input Sources tabs (and possibly the Keyboard pane). If it's just Terminal, check its preferences, especially the Settings section -> Keyboard tab. Oh, and just to be sure: what kind of keyboard is it? Anything at all unusual (non-Apple, non-US, etc).

Comment: Yes... small tilde everywhere and I'm using the built in keyboard on my 17"inch MBP running Lion

Comment: According to [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068470/tilde-not-recognized-in-mac-terminal/10785580#10785580), it might be a side effect of having the U.S. International input method selected (in Language & Text prefs), but that seems to cause issues for me in e.g. TextEdit but *not* Terminal. Still, I'd check the L&T prefs as the likely source of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

In your Mac keyboard if you type <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> or <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> then you will get `˜`.

If you want to type `~` use <kbd>shift</kbd> +<kbd>`</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

If you use US International keyboard layout like me, this may solve your problem:

Right after pressing `shift`+`˜`, press `space`.

If you just keep typing the path with forward slash, the terminal will interpret your tilde like a small tilde instead of the normal one. This happens because it tries to combine both characters into one instead of just inputing what you typed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).